# Java 8+ Mapping a Map of Lists

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a Map of Lists defined as such:

```
Map<Date,List<TimesheetContribution>> groupedByDate;
```

The class TimesheetContribution has a method getHours() which returns double.

What I want is:

```
Map<Date, Double> hoursMap = groupedByDate.entrySet().stream()...
```

Where the Map Values are the total hours from the TimesheetContribution instances.

The only way I can think of is something like this:

```
Map<Date, Double> toilAmounts = groupedByDate.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), value -> ???));
```

As you can see, I run into trouble when attempting to define the value mapper, and I'd need a nested stream, about which I am not comfortable.

Any suggestions? Or will I have to do this the old-fashioned way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do that as :

```
Map<Date, Double> hoursMap = groupedByDate.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, // for a key and not an entry
                e -> e.getValue().stream()
                        .mapToDouble(TimesheetContribution::getHours)
                        .sum()));
```